# Round the background color in the navigation drawer with Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm looking for a design similar to what the latest google apps do and i'm looking to get this rendering, I pretty much did something similar but I miss rounding the color, thank you very much

[The rendering I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS7x8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Rounded shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle"
   android:tint="@color/your_color">
   <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="32dp"
       android:topRightRadius="32dp" 
   />

   <!--    <size android:height="64dp" />--> // if you want to set height
</shape>
```

selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_shape" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

**app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector_item"** to your NavigationView.

Comment: thank you very much for your clear and precise explanation !